# How to send via a TCP socket in Kotlin (android)?

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, tcp

I hoped that if there was a `java.net.ConnectException`, the `onFailure` block would be called. But It doesn't work as expected.

Could you help?

```
        Socket(ip, port).use { socket: Socket ->
            val outputStream = socket.getOutputStream()
            outputStream.write(valueOn)
            outputStream.flush()
            state = State.FINISHED
        }.runCatching {
            state = State.FAILED
        }.onFailure {
            state = State.FAILED
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand very well kotlin but in java the exception is thrown when you call Socket (ip, port) which is a blocking call that connects the socket to remote server. The exception is thrown at this level and I am not sure if you catch it in your code as the Socket (ip,port) is outside the block.

Comment: `onFailure`should have some exception to show what went wrong

Comment: Not if it is created outside the block. NB You are leaking the socket. You should close the output stream if it exists, via all exits from this code.

Comment: @Hitchem - Ok, then Socket(ip,port) is a source of exception and it must be wrapped by try-catch. Tanks

Comment: You don't need to vandalise your own post to include an answer here.